# False/True Column constant

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**TL;DR**: I need this spark constant :

```scala
val False : Column = lit(1) === lit(0)
```

Any idea how to do it prettier ?

**Problem Context**

I want to filter a dataframe from a collection. For exemple

```scala
case class Condition(column: String, value: String)

val conditions = Seq(
  Condition("name", "bob"),
  Condition("age", 18)
)

val personsDF = Seq(
  ("bob", 30),
  ("anna", 20),
  ("jack", 18)
).toDF("name", "age")
```

When applying my collection to personsDF I expect:

```scala
val expected = Seq(
  ("bob", 30),
  ("jack", 18)
)
```

To do so, I am creating a filter from the collection and apply it to the dataframe:

```scala
val conditionsFilter = conditions.foldLeft(initialValue) {
  case (cumulatedFilter, Condition(column, value)) =>
    cumulatedFilter || col(column) === value
}

personsDF.filter(conditionsFilter)
```

Pretty sweet, right ?

But to do so, I need the neutral value of OR operator which is False. Since False doesn't exist is Spark I used:

```scala
val False : Column = lit(1) === lit(0)
```

Any idea how to do this without tricks ?

Comment: Doesn't `lit(false / true)` works?

Comment: your example given is not reproducable and code is not compiling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do :

```
val False : Column = lit(false)
```

This should be your `initialValue`, right? You can avoid that by using `head` and `tail`:

```
val buildCondition = (c:Condition) => col(c.column)===c.value

val initialValue = buildCondition(conditions.head)

val conditionsFilter = conditions.tail.foldLeft(initialValue)(
  (cumulatedFilter, condition) =>
    cumulatedFilter || buildCondition(condition)
)
```

Even shorter, you could use `reduce`:

```
val buildCondition = (c:Condition) => col(c.column)===c.value

val conditionsFilter = conditions.map(buildCondition).reduce(_ or _)
```